# Colums won't inline with each other in .card class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make cards inline next to each other in columns but they keep jumping under each other. I can't figure out why that happens even when I set col-md-6 so two of them should align next to each other.

I've checked for any issues with my columns and if they are right. I've also tried setting different column sizes so they count 12. That didn't work as well. I also couldn't fix the container issue. I need to know what I've done wrong so I can fix it on my own next time. Thanks for any help.

```html
<section id="jobs" class="py-5 bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <h1 class="display-3 text-uppercase text-black mb-0">pozice</h1>
        <div class="underline-green bg-green"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="images/assistant.jpg" alt="assistant" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">asistentka</h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-green mt-5">
              <h6 class="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="images/developer.jpg" alt="developer" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">developer</h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-green mt-5">
              <h6 class="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="images/advertiser.jpg" alt="advertiser" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">obchodník</h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-green mt-5">
              <h6 class="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display your card `inline`. You should put it in a same `row` instead of putting each card in a `row`.

```html
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
    <div className="card">
      <img src="images/assistant.jpg" alt="assistant" className="card-img-top">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h4 className="card-title text-capitalize">asistentka</h4>
        <p className="card-text">
          <h5 className="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
          <a href="" className="btn btn-green mt-5">
            <h6 className="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
    <div className="card">
      <img src="images/developer.jpg" alt="developer" className="card-img-top">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h4 className="card-title text-capitalize">developer</h4>
        <p className="card-text">
          <h5 className="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
          <a href="" className="btn btn-green mt-5">
            <h6 className="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
    <div className="card">
      <img src="images/advertiser.jpg" alt="advertiser" className="card-img-top">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h4 className="card-title text-capitalize">obchodník</h4>
        <p className="card-text">
          <h5 className="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
          <a href="" className="btn btn-green mt-5">
            <h6 className="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to put all column in the same row

```
<section id="jobs" class="py-5 bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <h1 class="display-3 text-uppercase text-black mb-0">pozice</h1>
        <div class="underline-green bg-green"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/assistant.jpg" alt="assistant" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">asistentka</h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-green mt-5">
                <h6 class="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
              </a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/developer.jpg" alt="developer" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">developer</h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-green mt-5">
                <h6 class="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
              </a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/advertiser.jpg" alt="advertiser" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">obchodník</h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Do našeho kolektivu hledáme kolegyni na pozici asistentky. Možná hledáme právě vás!</h5>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-green mt-5">
                <h6 class="btn-text text-white pt-1 px-4">Zjistit více</h6>
              </a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```